# Ошибка компиляции кода

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Недавно начал изучать C++ и попробовал поработать с функциями ввода вывода и Пматематическими функциями. Программа не компилируется и ругается на круглые скобки ")".
Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main() {
    float x, y;
    double r, d, b, c, i, j;
    scanf_s("%f%f%lf%lf", & x, & y, & i, & j);
    x = 4.5;
    y = 8.5;
    i = 3;
    j = 6;
    d = sqrt((exp(x / 2) + (exp(y / 2) * 3); b = abs(i - (exp(j / 3))); c = sin((x + y) - log(x) * 2); r = (d + b) / c; printf("%lf%lf%ef%lf", d, b, c, r);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а почему main имеет тип float?
скобку забыли в строке `d= sqrt((exp(x/2)+(exp(y/2)*3);`. А где нужна она - это уже Вам решать.

Comment: @Vorex, подозреваю, что компилятор (наряду с *кучей других ошибок*) сообщает, что проблема со скобками в строке 11. 

(Это где `sqrt`). (Добавьте 2 скобочки в конце, но другие ошибки останутся).

--

Рекомендую:

- сразу уйти с винды в \*nix

- взять (и изучить) нормальный текстовый редактор (например, emacs)

Если прорветесь через это, то мелкие проблемы с невозможностью самому найти несколько дурацких ошибочек сами отпадут.

Comment: 1. функция main должна возвращать int, а не float (в Си, если не ошибаюсь, возможен также void, в общем-то ваш код больше похож на Си, нежели на С++). Было бы любопытно услышать вашу точку зрени относительно того, зачем вам понадобилось менять его на float 
2. Скобки должны быть сбалансированы - открывающих должно быть столько же, сколько и закрывающих (добавьте закрывающую скобку в строке, где вычисляется корень
3. вместо abs используйте fabs 
4. вместо scanf_s лучше использовать просто scanf

Comment: @DreamChild - если у @Vorex студия, тогда на scanf будет ругаться (нужно либо ключики дописывать, либо использовать scanf_s)

Comment: @KoVadim помнится, от этого scanf_s можно избавиться с помощью нехитрых манипуляций. Точно не помню как, я отвечал на этот вопрос где-то полгода назад, но уже забыл (хотя штука не критичная, просто полезнее было бы изначально использовать более каноничные варианты)

Comment: @DreamChild прошу прошения за тип "float" неправильно оформил,я согласен в том что код больше похож на Си нежели на С++,но мой знакомый уверенно утверждал что это именно с++,а функцию "scanf_s" прописал потому что как подчеркнул @KoVadim я работаю на Visual Studio и при компиляции он требовал именно "Scanf_s"

Comment: @Vorex При определенной сноровке можно писать код так, что он будет одинаково компилироваться как в С так и в С++. Но это не делает такой код хорошим с++ кодом. Но код будет абсолютно валидным.

Comment: только что попробовал переписать код на турбо си,зарание исправив строку d= sqrt((exp(x/2)+(exp(y/2)*3); добавив скобки но проблема снова возникла с функцией "abs" так пробовал использовать заменить её на "fabs' но и эта затея не увенчалась успехом подробное описание ошибки "function 'abs'should have a prototypу"

Comment: вот [рабочий вариант][1]. Разве что замените в нем scanf на scanf_s при необходимости.

>но мой знакомый уверенно утверждал что это именно с++

если он утверждает, что это именно С++, а не Си, то он не прав - это и Си и С++ (причем это в большей степени именно Си). 

  [1]: http://ideone.com/VgZmp6

Comment: @Vorex, напишите

    #define abs(x) ({typeof(x) _x = (x); if (_x < 0) _x = -_x; _x;})

перед `main` и используйте g++ (или gcc -lm ...) и все заработает.

Только еще '\n' в конце строки форматов `printf` добавьте, а вывод совсем некрасивый.

Comment: Чтобы не ругался на scanf(), надо прописать что-то вроде #pragma warning (disable, XXXX), где вместо ХХХХ номер ворнинга (в синтаксисе могу немного ошибаться, давно не пользовался студией)

Answer (score 2):

По крайней мере, компилируется и выполняется:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float x, y;
    double r, d, b, c, i, j;
    scanf_s("%f%f%lf%lf", &x, &y, &i, &j);

    x = 4.5;
    y = 8.5;
    i = 3;
    j = 6;
    d = sqrt(exp(x / 2) + (exp(y / 2) * 3));
    b = abs(i - (exp(j / 3)));
    c = sin((x + y) - log(x) * 2);
    r = (d + b) / c;
    printf("%lf%lf%ef%lf", d, b, c, r);

    return 0;
}
```